# Kafka connector sink for topic not known in advance

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Generic explanation: My application consumes messages from a topic and then splits them into separate topics according to their id, so the topics are named like topic_name_id. My goal is to connect those new topics to a certain sink (s3 or snowflake, haven't decided) so that the messages published in those topics will end up there. However, i've only found ways to do this using a configuration file, where you connect the sink to a topic that already exists and which you know the name of. But here the goal would be to connect the sink to the topic created during the process. Is there a way this can be achieved?

If the above is not possible, is there a way to connect to the common topic with all the messages, but create different tables (in snowflake) or s3 directories according to the message ID? Adding to that, in case of s3, the messages are added as individual json files, right? No way to combine them into one file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The outgoing IDs are known, right?

Kafka Connect uses a REST API that you generate a JSON HTTP body using those IDs and finalized topic names, then use `requests`, for example, to publish and start connectors for those topics. You can do that directly from the process directly before starting the producer, or you can send a request with the ID/topic name to a lambda job instead, which communicates with the Connect API

When using different topics with the S3 Sink connector, there will be separate S3 paths **and** separate files, based on the number of partitions in the topic and the other partitioner settings defined in your connector property. Most S3 processes are able to read full S3 prefixes, though, so I don't imagine that being an issue

I don't have experience with the Snowflake connector to know how it handles different topic names.